# What do (or what can) artists do?

Tags: verbs, vocabulary

I am attempting to give a title to something I am writing but having a bit of difficulty finding a fitting verb to proceed the word 'art.' I am centering what I'm writing around this quote: "God's greatest work on earth is man; man's master art is leading men to God." I want my title to be "_____ the Master Art." As you can probably tell, my text deals with those who engage in the master art of leading men. I've thought of several possibilities—engaging, crafting, working, building, perfecting, etc.—but none seems to fit. I would be quite grateful for any suggestions.

In other words, like a painter *paints*, what verb could be used for "(Master) Art"-ing?

Comment: 'The architect of' could work

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is *writing advice*.

Comment: I think the usual term is *practice*: one practices an art, craft or discipline.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: nonsense. This is a word request, and a pretty good one, too.

Comment: The OP provided context for the question, which is exactly what everyone keeps demanding that posters provide.

Comment: @Martha: Okay - POB, if you like. Or Unclear, since (to me, at least) it's not obvious what "core" meaning OP seeks, after having rejected *engaging, crafting, working, building, perfecting*. In the end all I see is a request for a catchy title, with no clear specification here of exactly what the missing word should *mean*. A "standard" form for such titles is *"**Towards** the Master Art"*, but I don't see how the question leads us to that.

Comment: **Mastering the Master Art** or **The Art of Mastering**  To be honest I'm just guessing because I'm not entirely sure what you are asking.

Comment: What about **Leading Man, the Master Art**?

Comment: *None* seem to fit (there are more than two).  Could you say which, if any, are better than the others?  Or which particular characteristics of {action} are the ones you most want to express?

Comment: I'm not clear on the question, but does the word *leadership* cover the act of leading men? It's nowhere near your suggestions, so I'm not sure if it's what you're looking for.

Comment: "The Sword is Mightier Than Your Pen: How the Master Artist Kicks Ass Over Crappy Painters" or "My Spear Has More Reach That That Chisel: Sculptors Not A Lot Better"

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how well this would work for your title, but I feel like artists *create*.  Other common words are *make* or *do*, but those sound a little pedestrian for your work. **@StoneyB** suggested *practice* (in a comment on OP) which I think is very good, but if that ain't y'r fancy, here are my 2¢.

The problem is that most arts have specialized verbs; A painter paints, an poet writes, a dancer dances.  Given that, I think you'd want to use a verb that you could use with "leading men to God", such as

> *Engaging in* the Master Art

**Edit:** I see now that you already considered *engaging in*. Borrowing from other art forms, you could consider *perform*.

> *Performing* the Master Art

Failing that, I'd [Google "perform synonym"](https://www.google.com/search?q=perform%20synonym) and see where that can take you.